# Python get parameter outside of class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have this code :

```
class X(object):
    def func1(self, arg):
        print("Button {0} clicked".format(arg))
        return True

class Y(X):
    def func2(self):
       self.btn = QPushButton()
       self.btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.func1 , True ) )

#while func1 ==True :
       #do something
```

When I press the button, the arg parameter will be set to True.

I wish I could call function 1 outside of class, which will only be true if the button is pressed.

Comment: Where do you create an instance of your class?

Comment: "will only be true if the button is pressed". Which one do you mean? 1. when the mouse is *pressed* on the button at the time the function is called; 2. when the user *has previously* pressed the button at least once; 3. the button is in the "checked" state (assuming that `setCheckable(True)` or `setDown(True)` were used). Please try to make yourself more clear, and also provide a more comprehensive [mre] so that we *actually* understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: after the button is clicked(case 2) ,the arg parameter from func1 will get True value.I need to use this parameter outside the classes.

Comment: you should run all code directly in func when  you clicked button. And if you need value outside class then first you should create its instance `x = X()` with self.value = False` and button should sert `self.value = True` and later you can check `x.value == True`

Comment: if you want to use `while func1 ==True` then it may block all code and GUI will freeze. You may have to run this loop in separated `thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do something when you click button then you should do it directly inside `func1`.

But if you want to set some value which will be used later then you should use `self.value` to keep this value inside instance of this class - and later other function should get this value - without running function

```
class X(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = False   # set default value at start
        
    def func1(self, arg):
        print("Button {0} clicked".format(arg))
        self.value = True    # change value when click

class Y(X):
    def func2(self):
       self.btn = QPushButton()
       self.btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.func1, True))

# create instance of class

x = Y()

# access value in instance

while x.value is True:
   #do something
```

But `while`-loop may block event-loop in GUI and it may freeze GUI so it may need to run `while`-loop inside `thread`. Or it may need some `timer` to execute function periodically without loop and without `thread`.

```
class X(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = False   # set default value at start
        self.thread = None   # set default value at start
        
    def func1(self, arg):
        print("Button {0} clicked".format(arg))
        self.value = True    # change value when click

        if self.thread != None:
            print("thread already running")
        else:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(taget=self.long_running_loop)
            self.thread.start()
        
    def long_running_loop(self):
        while self.value is True:
             #do something
        self.thread = None   # inform function that it can run it again
        
class Y(X):
    def func2(self):
       self.btn = QPushButton()
       self.btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.func1, True))

# create instance of class

x = Y()
```

---

I show example with standard `Thread` but `PyQt` has own class `QThread` which you should use.